# (Android Layout) How to custom a View that can simply contains other View?

Tags: android

For example, I have a activity and it's layout xml file likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- something1 -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- something2 -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <!-- something3 -->

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is only used to express my problem and not the real layout used in my production environment. Each "something" refers to the specific layout and they are so different that I can't use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

As you can see, each "something" has similar `CardView`, `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout`, so I wonder if it is possible to make them as a custom view that I could simplify my layout as the following codes?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer
        android:id="@+id/something1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- something1 -->

    </com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer>

    <com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer
        android:id="@+id/something2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- something2 -->

    </com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer>

    <com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer
        android:id="@+id/something3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- something3 -->

    </com.example.myapplication.myCustomContainer>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of , and set each of your Views in his layout, as needed, but for that, you would need to create an xml item for each one of them.

Example:

```
            <include
                android:id="@+id/ic_something1"
                layout="@layout/something1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/ic_something2"
                layout="@layout/something2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

           <include
                android:id="@+id/ic_something3"
                layout="@layout/something3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Thank you, but by dong like this, I still have to copy similar `CardView`, `ScrollView` and `LinearLayout` into each xml file. This will cause maintenance difficulties and is not very elegant, especially when it needs to be repeated over 10 times. I am looking for some solution that likes custom view.